# How can I get root access on an Android 7.0 emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, root, su, android-studio-2.3

I'm developing an android application which writes some json files into the external storage. For development I want to have a look for the written json files.

I know that I can view these files with root access in `/data/data/package-name/`.

**But how can I get root access on the Android 7.0 Emulator?**

I already tried the su command in the adb shell and also adb root - but then I get this error message: `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`

Maybe you have some advice?

Comment: Would it be an option to try a debug build instead?

Comment: "I know that I can view these files with root access in /data/data/package-name/" -- that is not [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). That is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). So... are you writing to internal storage, or external storage?

Comment: I'm still using the debug build variant. I'm writing the json files to /data/data/<package-name>/files using context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName

Comment: Isn't this off-topic? I think this would be better on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry if I put my question in the wrong place ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm writing the json files to /data/data//files using context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName

That is internal storage, not external storage.

Use `adb shell run-as ... ???` to run commands as your app's user, which will allow those commands to access internal storage. Here, `...` is the application ID of your app, and `???` is a command.

So, for example, to list the contents of a typical location for `getFilesDir()` for an app whose user ID is `com.foo.bar`, use:

```
adb shell run-as com.foo.bar ls /data/data/com.foo.bar/files
```

This only works for debuggable apps.